# [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString returns all zeros

Tags: ios, objective-c, uniqueidentifier, udid

I have iPhone 4 with iOS 6.0 .

This property

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString
```

always returning the all zeros ( 00000-----) . 

Help me to fix this issue.

I have searched in the google.

I did the restart,deleted the app ... . But no use .

Answer (score 2):

identifierForVendor may need you to have a registered app ID in apple's member center and that it is unique (not wildcard IDs). As this is supposedly generating a UUID from some part of the app ID.

Is your app ID set to be unique like:
com.mycompany.myapp

in your plist?